# create a Jenkins job that allows us to choose the Java version based on the requirements of specific build deployments

Tags: jenkins

Our primary goal is to modernize our codebase by enabling the ability to build our application with either Java 8 or Java 17. We are exploring options to achieve this flexibility, including both manual specification and auto-detection of the Java version from parameters stored in build.gradle.

We are interested in understanding how we can configure Jenkins to select the Java version (either 8 or 17) dynamically during the build process.
The preference is to have this selection based on parameters specified in the build.gradle file, offering the flexibility to adapt to different project requirements.
Additionally, we seek guidance on best practices or considerations for aligning the build environment with the target deployment environment, ensuring compatibility and a smooth transition.
We appreciate any insights or recommendations you can provide to help us achieve this goal effectively. Thank you

Comment: if you are using Jenkins pipeline, you can add two environment variables like `JAVA_8_HOME` and `JAVA_17_HOME` on your slave, and use these variables to set JAVA_HOME or PATH accordingly in pipeline script.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to detect the Java version from some parameter stored in build.gradle and built the app using that version? Do you want to build your app in both environments? Does your build environment depend on the target environment where the application should be deployed? Please edit your question and add more details. Thanks

Comment: i have edited my question please look into this and help me out.